Wait for shards to be refreshed
When indexing documents using the bulk endpoint, one can set the parameter refresh=wait_for in order to wait shards to be refreshed.
What I wanna do is disable index refreshing interval, send all bulk requests, call the refresh endpoint POST /{index}/_refresh at the end and then wait until all the refresh is done.
Is it possible to be done using OS's API?
I searched through the documentation but couldn't find a way of doing this.

You can disable the refresh operation by adjusting refresh_interval to -1. You can do for _all indices or only one of them.

If you are trying to speed up the indexing speed you can also check
the following documentation.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/tune-for-indexing-speed.html

#disable the refresh
PUT index/_settings
{
  "refresh_interval": "-1"
}

#complete the bulk
POST /index/_bulk

#re-enable the refresh
PUT index/_settings
{
  "refresh_interval": null
}

#or just refresh manually
POST index/_refresh


index.refresh_interval How often to perform a refresh operation, which
makes recent changes to the index visible to search. Defaults to 1s.
Can be set to -1 to disable refresh. If this setting is not explicitly
set, shards that haven’t seen search traffic for at least
index.search.idle.after seconds will not receive background refreshes
until they receive a search request. Searches that hit an idle shard
where a refresh is pending will trigger a refresh as part of the
search operation for that shard only. This behavior aims to
automatically optimize bulk indexing in the default case when no
searches are performed. In order to opt out of this behavior an
explicit value of 1s should set as the refresh interval.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules.html#index-refresh-interval-setting


after calling POST index/_refresh, how to make sure all bulks were sent to shards?

When you call the _refresh endpoint, OpenSearch does wait for the refresh operation to complete before returning. However, you should ensure that all bulk requests have been processed before initiating the refresh.
Here is an example response from _refresh API call.
{ "_shards": { "total": 4, "successful": 2, "failed": 0 } }. As you can see in the response body all primary shards have been refreshed successfully.

Didn't know _refresh is synchronous, thanks.

You're welcome @cairo
